# How to update truststore at runtime without restarting the application in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

The use case is, in spring boot application, 
I am using jks `truststore`, and I want my application to update the `truststore` in context if it is updated at runtime without application restart.

Comment: truststore or keystore.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**set truststore before you code create the connection, file is ***.jks file*/
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStrore",file.getPath());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStrorePassword","changeit");
System.setProperty("https.protocols","TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv3");
```

Comment: but this will not reload the ssl configuration of the embedded tomcat server which is already started.

Comment: this just for runtime , not change the truststore of tomcat's